# I'm trying to display a text and when clicked the audio plays, when sound ends new text appears and when clicked that new audio plays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, audio

I was trying to create an array of all the text that goes in chronological order. This has to go on many times (click- sound plays - sound stops, next text appears click- sound play- next text etc.) I can't seem to get a new text to appear the old to go away and sound plays and stops then new text.

JavaScript File:

```
var nextText = (function() {
var myArray = ["text1","text2","text3"];
    var i = 0;
    return function() {
        $('#results').html(myArray[i%myArray.length]);
        i++;
    }
})();

function playSound(soundfile) {
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML=
    "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}
```

INDEX FILE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
<script src="main.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
<title>...</title>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<span id="myText"></span>

<myTextSize onmousedown="playSound('sound1.wav');">Text1</myTextSize>


<div id="nextText" style="display:none;">
<myTextSize onmousedown="playSound('sound2.wav');">Text2</myTextSize>
</div>

<div id="nextText3" style="display:none;">
<myTextSize onmousedown="playSound('sound3.wav');">Text3</myTextSize>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see all the text appears rather than Text1 (click-hear audio-audio ends-next text shows up. I need the same pattern over and over for several texts.

I added this code to my html file to try to get the click play stop next letter function working but to no avail.

@Seif Khalid I appreciate your rapid response. I was attempting for hours to implement this code but to no avail. I believe I am not doing it correctly. I tried responding in the comment section but adding code was weird formatting??

```
<OneTextSize id="#myText" onclick="sound2.play()" "sound2.onended()">myText1</OneTextSize>


<div id="#nextText" hidden>
<OneTextSize id="#nextText.show()" onclick="sound1.play()">myText2</OneTextSize>


<div id="#myText" style="display:none;">
  <OneTextSize onclick="sound1.play()">myText3</OneTextSize>
</div>
```

Comment: You have double quotes in your playSound function "<embed src=\"". Probably breaking the javascript.

You have other formatting issues as well.

Comment: @GeorgeDaniel thanks for the response, can you see what other formatting issues I have that could be breaking my code?

Comment: Hello Tonya, I was the one with the error when I tested your code. Your formatting is fine. My apologies.

Comment: @GeorgeDaniel oh ok do you know what I can do in my html code to make the javascript work?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't :(

Comment: To be honest, you have quite a bit of weird stuff going on. You're actually not doing any show/hide code in the javascript. Also, there is no such element as "myTextSize" or "OneTextSize".

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeDaniel I appreciate the observations

Answer (score 1):

How about this, add some audio tags to your html like so:

```
<audio id="sound1">
    <source src="sound1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="sound1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio id="sound2">
    <source src="sound2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="sound2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

And then in your javascript:

```
const sound1 = document.querySelector("#sound1");
const sound2 = document.querySelector("#sound2");
$("#myText").click(function() {
    sound2.play();
    sound2.onended = function() {
        $("#nextText").show(); // Ofcourse hide this in your css beforehand
    }
});
$("#nextText").click....//Repeat the same thing.
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is `onend(...)` ?

Comment: @Jonas W. I think it is supposed to be onended() I changed it in my code but it still didn't work

Comment: Oh my bad, it's sound2.onended = function() { // code here }

Comment: @SeifKhalid Thanks again for the response, can you tell if I did the code right when adding to the html file?

Comment: @iAmTonyaMISM Did you add the audio tags and the javascript?

Comment: Yes I scrapped my code and used your html and javascript and then added the code where it starts out <OneTextSize id="#myText...

Comment: @iAmTonyaMISM Also I don't understand the code. Why do the element ids have hashtags and javascript.

Comment: I am relearning this stuff. I haven't been programming since 2012. I'm trying to get back into the swing of things and not doing so great. I've mixed and mashed code to get it to work but it's not going beyond the next part I need it to do.